# Angle Bisector Theorem

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle with angle bisector $CL$ $(L\in AB)$ and median $CM$ $(M\in AB)$. I should find $LM$ if $BC=a,AC=b,AB=c(a>b)$.
[image]
By the angle bisector theorem, $\dfrac{AL}{BL}=\dfrac{AC}{BC}$ or $AL=\dfrac{AC\cdot BL}{BC},BL=\dfrac{AL\cdot BC}{AC}$. We know $LM=AM-AL=BL-BM$ and I am not sure how to approach the problem further.

Comment: You have the extra equation $AL+LB=AB$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Should I plug $AL=\dfrac{AC\cdot BL}{BC}$ and $BL=\dfrac{AL\cdot BC}{AC}$ in the equation you wrote? I don't see what to do with it.

Comment: Eliminate one of $AL$ or $BL$.

Comment: How? Can you start your idea because I can't  get this right.

Comment: $BL=AB-AL$ maybe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\frac{AL}{LB}=\frac{b}{a},$$ we obtain:
$$AL=\frac{bc}{a+b}$$ and
$$LM=AM-AL=\frac{c}{2}-\frac{bc}{a+b}=\frac{c(a-b)}{2(a+b)}.$$

We can get $AL$ by the following way: 
$$\frac{AL}{c-AL}=\frac{b}{a}$$ or
$$\frac{c-AL}{AL}=\frac{a}{b}$$ or
$$\frac{c}{AL}-1=\frac{a}{b}$$ or
$$\frac{c}{AL}=1+\frac{a}{b}$$ or
$$\frac{c}{AL}=\frac{a+b}{b}$$ or
$$\frac{AL}{c}=\frac{b}{a+b}$$ or
$$AL=\frac{bc}{a+b}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! How did we obtain $AL=\dfrac{bc}{a+b}$ from $\dfrac{AL}{LB}=\dfrac{b}{a}$?

Comment: Can you explain this to me?

Comment: $AL+LB=c$ and just solve the system.

Comment: We are talking about the following system, right: $\cases{\dfrac{AL}{LB}=\dfrac{b}{a} \\ AL+LB=c}$?

Comment: Can you show me how to solve it for $AL$?

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. The first time when I was trying to solve the problem $AL>AM$ on my drawing. How can we see that $M$ is between $L$ and $B$?

Comment: @Nikol Dimitrova Because $a>b$ gives $LB>AL.$